# PHPExcel multiple foreach loops

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel

I want to display all the rows from a table with the corresponding column names above, which works. The problem is that it removes the first row from the results below the column names. It's as if the column row is somehow counted as a row in the while loop that displays the results, but I can't figure it out.

If I remove the column names code shown below all of the results are shown.

```
//COLUMN NAMES
foreach($headings as $heading) { 

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
    $col++;

}
```

All of the code shown below.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `" . $_SESSION['sess_table'] . "` ORDER by ID ASC";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) { 

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($excelTitle);

    $headingsrow = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $headings = array_keys($headingsrow);

    //COLUMN NAMES
    $rowNumber = 1; 
    $col = 'A'; 
    foreach($headings as $heading) { 

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
        $col++;

    } 

    //RESULTS
    $rowNumber = 3;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) { 

        $col = 'A'; 
        foreach($row as $key => $cell) { 

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell); 
            $col++;

       } 

       $rowNumber++;

    } 

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2'); 

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $excelFilename . '.xls"'); 
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 

    $objWriter->save('php://output'); 
    exit(); 

}
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you have to increase the $rowNumber not the $col.

Comment: `$headingsrow = $result->fetch_assoc();` doesn't just fetch your headings, it also fetches your first row of data, which you then discard

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
$rowNumber = 1; 
$col = 'A'; 
foreach($headings as $heading) { 

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
    $col++;

}
```

you have increased the $col value instead of increasing $rowNumber value.

try this,

```
$rowNumber = 1; 
$col = 'A'; 
foreach($headings as $heading) { 

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
    $rowNumber++;

}
```

Comment: No, thats not it. That code is only for the column names, which display correctly. It's the code below for the results that ignore the first row that I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching the first row to retrieve your headings, but then discarding it even though it contains data that you want to write as well

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) { 

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($excelTitle);

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $headings = array_keys($row);

    //COLUMN NAMES
    $rowNumber = 1; 
    $col = 'A'; 
    foreach($headings as $heading) { 

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
        $col++;

    } 

    //RESULTS
    $rowNumber = 3;
    do {
        $col = 'A'; 
        foreach($row as $key => $cell) { 

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell); 
            $col++;

       } 

       $rowNumber++;

    } while ($row = $result->fetch_row());

}
```